# How do you interpret "as the eyes" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

suppose that, in the context of a list of instructions to make a snowman, there is the following sentence:

"Stick a pair of small pebbles into the head above the nose as the eyes."

I mean that the pebbles represent the eyes of the snowman, and that later instructions referring to "the eyes" actually refer to those pebbles.

In this sentence, is the way I'm using "as the eyes" correct and understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**as the eyes** is grammatically wrong. The sentence should be

> "Stick a pair of small pebbles into the head above the nose **for** the eyes."

If you want to use **as**, the less preferred sentence could be

> "Stick a pair of small pebbles into the head above the nose **to act as** the eyes."

Comment: Aha, thank you. Would you say it is a common mistake, though?

Comment: It is quite common to encounter such uses of as. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Actually, "as the eyes" is not wrong, it's just less idiomatic and, in the above context, confusing.  It would be perfectly fine to say "As the eyes, stick a pair of small pebbles into the head, above the nose."